# Reading Hindi excel file

Tags: c#

I have an excel file in which there are text and images in Hindi font. Now, my requirement is to read the excel file and store the binary data in database or anything which later can be converted into the same font.

When I read the excel in normal way through C# it gets some roman characters for hindi fonts without doing any encoding or decoding.

I use this code to read the excel file:

```
string fileName = string.Format("{0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); 
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName); 
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [workSheetNameHere$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet(); 
adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");
DataTable data = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"];
```

EDIT: This code is used by me to read the excel file

```
string fileName = string.Format("{0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); 
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
data source={0};    
Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [workSheetNameHere$]",
                                                        connectionString); 
var ds = new DataSet(); 
adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere"); 
DataTable data = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"];
```

Comment: What locale are you using? And have you tried setting the text encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: string fileName = string.Format("{0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [workSheetNameHere$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");

DataTable data = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"];

Comment: This code is used by me to read the excel file

Comment: @shanky I tried with unicode excel file (`.xls`) and it worked. Can you upload your excel file somewhere so I can have a look at it?